# Web Bluetooth API not showing custom services

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth Low Energy device that has two services:

1. Battery service
2. Custom service to send GPS coordinates

My JavaScript can be seen here - https://reverent-turing-cbe90d.netlify.app/ - you will need your own Google Maps API key but the Bluetooth functionality doesn't require the map.

The uuid of the custom service is 00000001-5D8B-474C-AC79-AB44EDE9EF2F.

The code I am using for the peripheral device can be found here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uljTZe2mbeOAsqiXuf1iLnQBFB91PO70/view?usp=sharing

Both services work on desktop Chrome 86.0.4240.198 however using Chrome 86.0.4240.198 on my OnePlus 8 Pro I can only see the Battery service.

How can I get this working on both desktop and mobile?

Answer (score 0):

On mobile, do you see the device in the bluetooth browser picker?
If not, can you use `optionalServices` and see it?

```js
navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
  filters: [
    {
      services: ["battery_service"],
      optionalServices: ["00000001-5d8b-474c-ac79-ab44ede9ef2f"],
    },
  ],
});
```

If you see them, I'd assume `getPrimaryServices()` doesn't return your "Custom service to send GPS coordinates".
If so, can you try calling it specifically with code below and sharing the error?

```js
const customService = await server.getPrimaryService("00000001-5d8b-474c-ac79-ab44ede9ef2f");
```